# Small code, value isn't carried

Tags: java, variables

I've got this problem, I have a java file that obtains 2 variables from another file and is supposed to add them together and return the summed value. So far it works on obtaining the values aFirst and aSecond but I'm not sure why value one and two is lost (is back at 0) when it gets to the sum method. This is for an assignment I have for homework.

```
public class Pair
{
    private double one, two ;
    public Pair(double aFirst, double aSecond)
    {
        double one = aFirst;
        double two = aSecond;
    }

    public double sum() 
    {
        double xys = one + two;
        return(xys);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you find an answer you like, you can "tick" it to accept that answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're declaring `one` and `two` as local variables, shadowing the instance variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand it. I tried using this.one but I was using it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6):

the problem is the constructor. you are creating local variables and not using the class fields

```
private double one, two ;
public Pair(double aFirst, double aSecond)
{
    this.one = aFirst;
    this.two = aSecond;
}
```

you can do it without the "this." but dont put type ahead

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to access the class member variables in override cases when you have the same variable name in local scope and in the class members.